# Can I set up an integrity constraint to multiple tables on one column?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which contains a list of components associated with a device.

```
dev_comps
=========
dev_id comp_type comp_id
------ --------- -------
     1         A    1234
     1         A    1237
     1         A    1238
     1         B    5678
     1         C    1234
     2         A    1235
```

(yes I can have multiples of each kind of component on the device, otherwise I'd just attach them to the device table instead of having a junction table)

I also have several table for the types of components (which of course all have a little bit different options each other).

```
comp_a
======
comp_a_id color style
--------- ----- -----
     1234   red glass
     1235  blue  wood

comp_c
======
comp_c_id style length
--------- ----- ------
     1234 glass      5
     1235  wood      7
```

Is it possible to set up an integrity constrain between `dev_comps.comp_id` and `comp_a.comp_a_id`; and `dev_comps.comp_id` and `comp_c.comp_c_id`; etc.?

In general I don't want my app/users to be able to create an entry in `dev_comps` where I don't have a matching `comp_id` in the corresponding `comp_*` table.

Or, is there a better way to do this?

---

**Edit**

I've come to the conclusion that what I'm really doing here is **Column Overloading**. Which as I recall from my old Intro to DBs course is generally considered a poor design. Is there a clean way out of this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't have a foreign key constraint that refers to one of two possible parent tables.  There are two common approaches to this sort of issue:

1. You can combine all the `comp_*` tables into a single table, adding in a `comp_type` column.  Presumably, this would mean that many attributes would be NULL for every row since each type of component only has a small number of the available attributes.  You can add constraints that ensure that the appropriate set of columns are `NULL` or `NOT NULL` depending on the `comp_type` but you'll waste a bit of space.  On the other hand, storing `NULL` values, particularly at the end of the row, is pretty cheap.
2. You can create a `master_component` table that just has the `comp_id` and `comp_type`.  The various `comp_*` tables could have foreign keys that point to that table (though you'd want `comp_type` to be added at least as a virtual column).  And `dev_comps` could point at the `master_component` table.

Of course, there are other options depending on the specifics of the problem.  If there are a large number of components with lots of different attributes, such that combining tables would produce a `master_component` table with hundreds of columns, it may make more sense to have a single `master_component` table with a `component_attribute` table that stores attributes as rows rather than as columns.  But that's more of a specialized case not something I'd start with.

Comment: I see what you're doing here. That would effectively change my problem from Column Overloading to Table Overloading. This would certainly allow me to add the required integrity constraints. The negative would be that I would have to treat the same table differently in code, depending on the context.

Comment: @BIBD - "column overloading" generally refers to storing two logically different values in the same column.  That's not what you're doing and not what either of my suggestions are advocating.  In #1, you'd still have a `color` column in your table, it would just be NULL if the component doesn't have a color.  If you wanted to, you could create views for each component with either solution that expose just the columns that are appropriate for that component type.